# Remove kernels installed from source from Fedora 34

Tags: linux, fedora, linux-kernel

I have compiled and installed a linux kernel from source, installing it with `sudo make install`, but the system failed to boot.

How can I remove the kernel installed as such?

Comment: The Fedora 34 grub usually has three options → the three last kernels. My example: line1, Fedora (5.13.12-200.fc34.x86_64) .... line2, Fedora (5.13.9-200.fc34.x86_64) .... line3, Fedora (5.13.8-200.fc34.x86_64) ...... : Please choose a valid kernel version → boot, and  you can remove the invalid kernel entry.

Comment: @KnudLarsen my question is: how can I remove the invalid kernel entry? I was able to boot from an old kernel

Comment: Suggest : 1. Please have a look in /boot/ , and delete vmlinuz-??-new, etc. files-new-home-made . ...... 2. Then do `# dnf reinstall kernel-core` . File list https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kcS-ND-YQfVXWawS2hSSAqq9BfgVIzOR/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The files in /boot are managed with [kernel-install(8)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/kernel-install.html) from systemd. Run `kernel-install remove <version>` to remove kernel files and boot loader entries for the kernel with the given version.

Note that if you installed kernel modules, you still need to remove those manually from /lib/modules.